# How does a browser get a website's logo?

Tags: browser

How does an internet browser get the logo/favicon of a website? I run a website and it'll be useful if I know how exactly this happens.

For example, an HTTP request to somewhere might return the value but I'm interested in knowing how this happens in details.

Like how it gets the image, how it implements it. How can I manipulate it?

Comment: The code for the website indicates what icon to use.

Comment: `GET /favicon.ico` - a normal HTTP GET request, no magic here. You can also specify the icon in a HTML page using the `meta name="shortcut icon"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the 'technical' term for it is a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)

It's traditionally an .ico file that's 16x16 pixels, and placed at the root of your website directory

With modern browsers. PNGs and GIFs are very widely supported and there's other formats supported too. You can also embed these as tags.

Comment: "Root of my website directory": I don't see any file that might relate to my website's logo... I've uploaded the logo via my theme, but I don't know where it's stored. But there's nothing in root directory...

Comment: You apparently can also use tags - which might be the case here. The wikipedia link I've referenced is probably worth reading through. I suspect if you're using modern webpages, or stuff like virtual servers, things may differ somewhat.

Comment: Ah I read it. I think I can figure out the rest on my own. BTW your reputation is 66.6, doesn't make you uneasy?

Comment: I'm waiting for it to hit 66,666 actually!

Comment: Haha good luck in that